# I declared variables, but the variables seems to be a random value

Tags: c, linux, volatile, barrier

If I declare `start_tsc` and `end_tsc` with `volatile`, then everything goes well.
If not, after perform `uint64_t end_tsc = start_tsc + (g_cpuhz_ms * MD_WAIT_MAX_TIME_MS);` Gdb prints `end_tsc` which is a super-big value(g_cpuhz_ms and MD_WAIT_MAX_TIME_MS are normal values ).
I can't understand that `end_tsc` definitely rely on `start_tsc`, why compile optimizes the order. Or anything happend?

```
static uint64_t get_tsc() {
    unsigned a, d;
    __asm__ __volatile__("rdtsc" : "=a" (a), "=d" (d));
    return ((uint64_t)a) | (((uint64_t)d) << 32);
}  

main() {
    uint64_t start_tsc = get_tsc();//get cpu clock now
    uint64_t end_tsc = start_tsc + (g_cpuhz_ms * MD_WAIT_MAX_TIME_MS);
}
```

Added from comment:
Here is the compiling result which compiled with `-E`

```c
static inline uint64_t md_timer_get_tsc(void)
{
    unsigned a, d;

    __asm__ __volatile__("rdtsc" : "=a" (a), "=d" (d));

    return ((uint64_t)a) | (((uint64_t)d) << 32);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What are "normal" values? Did you check the assembler output your compiler created? Can you show it? What do you mean with "rely on `start_tsc`"? As you add some value to `start_tsc` the result must rely on that initial value. Please add this information to your question. You can use the `edit` button below to add missing information.

Comment: “normal” means they are const value, "rely on start_tsc" means the value of `end_tsc` depends on the value of `start_tsc`. later i ll give you the assenbler output

Comment: Here is the compiling result which compiled with -E（sry that i really dont know how to format code to be human-readable）
    `static inline uint64_t md_timer_get_tsc(void)
    {
        unsigned a, d;
        __asm__ __volatile__("rdtsc" : "=a" (a), "=d" (d));
        return ((uint64_t)a) | (((uint64_t)d) << 32);
    }`@Gerhardh

Comment: Please do not describe values but show them. Which values do you get, what would you expect. Also `-E` only shows preprocessor output. You should check assembler output to see what happens. And again: If you add something to variale `a`, how do you think, the result could be independent from `a`?

Comment: If that is your complete code, there is no reason why the compiler should create any code for `main` except calling `get_tsc`. As you do not use the values of those 2 variables, they could be removed completely.